# Is Oppermann's still a conjecture?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Recently learned about [Oppermann's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oppermann%27s_conjecture).  However, the google search results also returned a link to this article [A SHORT PROOF FOR OPPERMANN'S CONJECTURE](https://vixra.org/pdf/1502.0134v1.pdf). (converted into latex format below)

I see the proof points to [viXra](https://vixra.org/why) not [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/), so

> It is inevitable that viXra will therefore contain e-prints that many
> scientists will consider clearly wrong and unscientific.

**Question**

I'm curious if there's a logic error in the authors proof below?

---

**Theorem 1.** [Oppermann’s conjecture](https://www.chrishenson.net/static/article_files/zeta/hardy_intro.pdf) Given an integer, $n > 1$, there is, at least, one prime number, $p_1$, such that $n^2 - n < p_1 < n^2$; and, at least, another prime number, $p_2$, such that $n^2 < p_2 < n^2 + n$.

---

We utilize an alternative statement: Let $\pi(n)$ denotes the classical prime-counting function. Thus,

$$\pi(n^2 - n) < \pi(n^2) < \pi(n^2 + n), \quad (1)$$

or, equivalently,

$$0 < \pi(n^2) - \pi(n^2 - n) \quad (2)$$

and

$$0 < \pi(n^2 + n) - \pi(n^2). \quad (3)$$

---

In present, we will need of the lower bound for prime-counting function:

**Theorem 2.** (Hardy-Wright’s estimate) For $n \geq 1$, then
$$\pi(n) \geq \frac{\log n}{2\log 2}. \quad (4)$$

**Proof.** See [[6, Theorem 20, page 21]](https://www.chrishenson.net/static/article_files/zeta/hardy_intro.pdf).

---

Now, we present a new proof for Oppermann’s conjecture.

**Proof.** For $n \geq 1$. We set $n^2 + n$, $n^2$ and $n^2 - n$, respectively, into $n$ in Eq. (4), and obtain

$$\pi(n^2 + n) > \frac{\log n + \log(n + 1)}{2\log 2}, \quad (5)$$

$$\pi(n^2) > \frac{2\log n}{2\log 2}, \quad (6)$$

and

$$\pi(n^2 - n) > \frac{\log n + \log(n - 1)}{2\log 2}. \quad (7)$$

Subtracting (5) to (6), we meet

$$\pi(n^2 + n) - \pi(n^2) > \frac{\log n + \log(n + 1) - 2\log n}{2\log 2} = \frac{\log(n + 1) - \log n}{2\log 2} > 0,$$

since $\log(n + 1) > \log n$. Hence, $\pi(n^2 + n) - \pi(n^2) > 0$.

On the other hand, subtracting (6) to (7), we get

$$\pi(n^2) - \pi(n^2 - n) > \frac{2\log n - \log n - \log(n - 1)}{2\log 2} = \frac{\log n - \log(n - 1)}{2\log 2} > 0,$$

since $\log n > \log(n - 1)$. Thus, $\pi(n^2) - \pi(n^2 - n) > 0$. This gives us the desired result.

Comment: "Subtracting (5) to (6)": $6>5$, $3>1$, does it mean $6-5 > 3-1$?

Comment: How did $\geq$ become $>$? Looks clearly wrong to me.

Comment: As I understand it, this was known as Legendre's conjecture first, with the statement being that there is always a prime between $n^2$ and $(n+1)^2$, and unless I am mistaken this less-restrictive conjecture is as yet unproven...

Comment: Going forward, I suggest that you simply ignore anything from xivra. The arxiv doesn't have very strong posting requirements, and the small work necessary to meet them is far less than the very hard work it takes to contribute meaningfully to math.

Comment: The particular flaw here is unrelated. The problem is that $A > B$ and $C > D$ does not mean that $(A - C) > (B - D)$. For example, $1 > 0$ and $1 > -100$, but $(1 - 1) \not > (0 + 100)$. Thus when the purported proof attempts to subtract lower bounds for $\pi(n^2 + n)$ and $\pi(n^2)$, they lose all inequalities.

Comment: The answer to the title is clearly "yes", The best known general uuper bound for the gap for sufficiently large primes $p$ is still $p^{0.525}$